# Referencing belongs_to associations in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have activerecords attatched to my users in my `address` column via `user_id` I am trying to render a record belonging to a certain user in my view page but i keep on getting `NoMethodError`

How do I call activerecords attached to a user id?

#### users.haml (view)

```
.row
  .col-md-12
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Customer
          %th Phone
          %tbody
            - @users.each do |user|
              %tr
                %td= link_to user.name, admin_customers_user_single_url(user.id)
                %td= user.address.phone // this part
```

#### user.rb (model)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  # associations
  has_many :addresss
  has_many :orders
  ...
end
```

#### address.rb (model)

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders

  validates :name, 
            :phone, 
            :address, 
            :city, 
            :country, 
            :post_code,
            :province,
            presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 1}

  # valid options for contact field
  CONTACT_FIELD = ['al', 'ph', 'em', 'dn', 'tx']
  validates_inclusion_of :contact, :in => CONTACT_FIELD

  def get_contact
    contact = {"al" => "All", "ph" => "Phone Only", "em" => "Email Only", "dn" => "Do Not Contact", "tx" => "Text Only"}
    contact[self.contact]
  end

  def get_full_addr
    buff = ""
    buff << self.address
    buff << ", " + self.address_2 if !(self.address_2.nil?)
    buff << ", " + self.city
    buff << ", " + self.province
    buff << ", " + self.country
    buff << ", " + self.post_code
  end
end
```

#### customers_controller.rb (controller)

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  # users
  def users
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        @users = @users.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
      end
    end
  end

  def get_user
    @users = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: What file/line of code causes that error?

Comment: `%td= user.address.phone` // this part

Comment: it should be addresses instead of addresss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggestion 1: plural for address is addresses

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  # associations
  has_many :addresses  
  has_many :orders
  ...
end
```

Corrected view:

```
.row
  .col-md-12
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Customer
          %th Phone
          %tbody
            - @users.each do |user|
              %tr
                %td= link_to user.name, admin_customers_user_single_url(user.id)
                %td= user.addresses.map(&:phone) // all phones will be shown one by one if this man has many addresses.
```

Comment: One more thing, `user.addresses.map(&:phone).join('<br>').html_safe`

Answer (score 1):

User has many addresses, so you need to use plural form

```
= user.addresss.first.phone
```

Not sure `addresss` is grammatically right (I'm not a native speaker), but it looks weird for me.

Comment: `addresss` is correct on my side but when i do this i get `uninitialized constant User::Addresss`

Comment: `user.addresss.first.phone` causes an uninitialized constant ?
Please provide an `Address` model code

Answer (score 1):

There is typo/mistake in your `User` associations:

```
has_many :addresss
```

If your user has one address, than you must use `has_one` relation:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_one :address
  ...
end
```

More info here: [Link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association)

Comment: `has_many :addresss` is correct as a user will have multiple addresses (i should reword the spelling:p )

Comment: In that case you need to decide what address/phone to show in the view. Since you'll have `addresss` (or whatever) that return collection of AR objects.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `addresses` instead of `addresss`

```
2.2.2 :001 > a = "address"
 => "address" 
2.2.2 :002 > a.pluralize
 => "addresses"
```

You can use rails pluralize method to check the plural of any word - 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/pluralize